# How to auto reply with a message to the email address in a message body

Tags: vba, email, gmail, applescript

I am trying to figure out how to use gmail or another email client to automatically reply to an email address found in the message body.

The email is at the end of the received message and would be easy to detect. I just don't know how I can get an email client to do it.

Once the email is detected, I'd want to set a message to that email to send every time a new message from the same from email address is received. (Where the message came from and who the message should be replied to are different addresses.)

How can I create a filter, rule, or script that will take a email address from the body of an email message, and send it a new message?

Thanks.

Someone has already asked a similar question, but the response that I saw was not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just confirming your question first. Are you asking:

> How can I use G-mail or some other mail client to deliver a new e-mail to a new recipient along with an intended message body based upon a subset of the original message with delivery instructions? Both the intended recipient and new message would be specified somewhere inside the original message body.

If this is what you are suggesting, I believe you would be asking for trouble even considering this. What you would be essentially doing is creating an [open mail relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay). Mail relaying is not a good idea without some form of authentication and network level restrictions by IP, etc. Encoding a client to do this at that level would not be wise. For more information as to why this is a bad idea, see this link: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay

I do hate to sound negative, but if you could explain your purpose here, we might be able to come up with a more acceptable, net-friendly secure alternative. :)